# How to show relative time in react.js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, timestamp, momentjs, dayjs

I'm building social media app using `next.js`. I want to display relative time in my project.

**Expected output :**

just now
2 minutes ago
1 hour ago
2 days

I want to retrieve time from `MongoDB` document[image: document]

Tried to use `moment` and `dayjs`, but i'm facing some trouble in getting started. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [react-timeago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeago):

```
import TimeAgo from 'react-timeago';

...
<TimeAgo date={date} />
```

This will generate the auto-generated text that looks like:

```
2 minutes ago
3 days ago
4 months ago
1 year ago
```

They also support [custom formatting options](https://github.com/nmn/react-timeago#formatter-optional).

Comment: There's an error while showing time using react-timeago. I'm retrieving time from mongoDB. Please see the attached image, I want to get createdAt time and use it for showing relative time

Comment: Your `createdAt` value seems to be correctly formatted. What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: Sir `2023-08-17T17:00:08.682+00:00` This is the `createdAt` time recorderd for the data created at `2023-08-17 22:30:02`. How can I split exact time from `createdAt` field?

Comment: What happens if you put the `createdAt` field directly as `date` prop value?

Answer (score 1):

You need not use any external npm package to do this.

```
export const getTimeDifference = (targetDate: string) => {
  const difference = new Date().getTime() - new Date(targetDate).getTime()

  if (difference > 0) {
    const timeLeft = {
      days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
      minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60),
    }
    return timeLeft
  }

  return undefined
}
```

You can get the time difference here.

And

```
const timeDiff = getTimeDifference(your Mongodb time string)
const timeString = `${timeDiff.days} days ${timeDiff.hours} hours ${timeDiff.minutes} minutes ${timeDiff.seconds} seconds`
```